# Double click to close side panel

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a sliding panel using jQuery and jQuery Cookie and its so close to working perfect.

```
$(function () {
if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
    $('#slideOut').css('right', '-345px');
    $(".slideClose").addClass('hideBtn');
    $(".slideOpen").removeClass('hideBtn');
}
});

$('#slideClick').click(function () {
var it = $(this).data('it') || 1;
switch (it) {

    case 2:
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-345px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(".slideClose").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideOpen").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;

    case 1:
        $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(".slideOpen").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideClose").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;

}
it++;
if (it > 2) it = 1;
$(this).data('it', it);
//$.cookie('myCookieName', '1')
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 1;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("myCookieName", "foo", { expires: date });
});
```

When the panel was closed it took two clicks to open it, someone suggested to change the order of "case 1" and "case 2" which worked however now it takes two clicks to close the panel, any help would be appricated.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/u8ccv03s/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your starting case. The reason that it requires 2 clicks is because your first click is to slide the sidebar out, but it's already out.

Change:`var it = $(this).data('it') || 1;`

To: `var it = $(this).data('it') || 2;`

Should be good after that.

If you want to make sure you avoid the double click issue with cookies, just make sure you add that case to your cookies function to update the data.

```
$('#slideClick').data('it', 1);
```

Comment: Nice one second before me :)

Comment: Thanks that works but now it takes two clicks to open, can't win lol https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/u8ccv03s/8/

Comment: I should probably be more specific, it now requires to clicks if you refresh the page and the cookie keeps it shut.

Comment: Well, that is a separate issue. You need to figure out whether or not the bar is opened or closed at the start of the event. My overall suggestion for this would be control the animation using CSS3, and then just toggle a class whenever the button is clicked

Comment: So close but so far away, looks like back to the drawing board, thanks for your help.

Comment: @webmonkey237 well if you add this: `$('#slideClick').data('it', 1);` to your cookie function it should solve your problem. At least adding something like that.

Comment: Awesome, that now works perfect! That saved me from having to start again, thanks again, its been a learning curve for me.

Comment: @webmonkey237 not a problem. Updated my answer to include that. So long as you understand why I made those changes, these should be some good lessons for debugging, and understanding how the browser works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.dblclick()` instead of `.click()`. More information here: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ and modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8ccv03s/4/

Comment: Sorry maybe my title was misleading, I don't want to double click to open the panel, at the moment you have to double click to close it the first time, I need just a single click, thanks for the answer anyway :)